# What is this flange on an inductor?

Tags: pcb-design, switch-mode-power-supply, inductor

Usually I have seen pads beneath inductors.  What is the purpose of this flange on an inductor? Why is it constructed like that?

[image]

Context: I am  looking for low profile inductors (<1.2mm) and  could not find any regular shaped (square/ rectangle) inductors meeting the specificaton (1uH, 8A- Isat.)

Comment: Could be for solder inspection. The Vishay IHLP1616AB almost meets that at 7A.

Answer (score 4):

This is a high power inductor.

It looks like where the joint is made between the contacts and the flat wire winding. The ball schematically represents a weld, real ones would like a bit different (and a bit messier).

[image]

Nothing you should have to worry about much footprint-wise, just follow the datasheet recommendations.

Comment: Am I the only one who finds this a bit weird? Why would a manufacturer need a joint for a [flat inductor](https://p.globalsources.com/IMAGES/PDT/BIG/464/B1182433464.jpg) while they are capable of pulling (or bending?) the ends to the sides? No offense. I'm not telling you anything about your answer. Just the production technique seems a bit weird to me.

Comment: @RohatKılıç The wire inside, if flat, isn't in the same plane as the feet anyways so that's a nightmare bend.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I'm guessing it has to do with keeping the contacts very flat and providing adequate contact area for the mass and current- it's only 1.2mm thick, which is next to nothing.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very high permeability amorphous ferrite with Cobalt Iron, semi-shielded in an extreme low profile.  You won't find any smaller parts with these specs.

> I am looking for low profile inductors (<1.2mm) and could not find any regular shaped (square/ rectangle) inductors meeting the specificaton (1uH, 8A- Isat.)

< 1.2mm

- very low probability of meeting your tight specs.

= 1.2 mm max.

- use these [readily avail.]

The outside termination is possibly ultrasonically welded.